# jQuery code to dynamically update background-color of bootstrap progress-bar based on value range

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar, background-color

I am trying to write jQuery code to update the background-color of a bootstrap progress-bar based on the width of the progress-bar. So for example, if it is below 50%, then the bar should be red. If it is between 50-70% the progress bar should be yellow and if it is above 70% it should be green. I need the code to take the value of the progress-bar and check in these ranges and change the background.

HTML

```
<td><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:100%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valumax="100" >100%</div></div></td>
<td><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:80%" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valumax="100" >80%</div></div></td>
<td><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:90%" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valumax="100" >90%</div></div></td>
```

jQuery

```js
<script>
 var value = $('.progress-bar').css('width');            
 $(document).ready(function(){
   if(value < 50){
   $('.progress-bar').css('background-color', 'red'); 
   } 
   else if(value >= 50) && (value < 70){
   $('.progress-bar').css('background-color', 'yellow');
   }
 });  
</script>
```

```html
<tr>
                          <td><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:98%" aria-valuenow="98" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valumax="100" >98%</div></div></td>
                          <td><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:72%" aria-valuenow="72" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valumax="100" >72%</div></div></td>
                          <td><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:82%" aria-valuenow="82" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valumax="100" >82%</div></div></td>
                          <td><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:56%" aria-valuenow="56" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valumax="100" >56%</div></div></td>
                          <td><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valumax="100" >75%</div></div></td>
                          <td><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:100%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valumax="100" >100%</div></div></td>
                          <td><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valumax="100" >30%</div></div></td>
                          <td><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:33%" aria-valuenow="33" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valumax="100" >33%</div></div></td>
                          <td><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:77%" aria-valuenow="77" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valumax="100" >77%</div></div></td>
                          <td><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:98%" aria-valuenow="98" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valumax="100" >98%</div></div></td>
                          <td><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:98%" aria-valuenow="98" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valumax="100" >98%</div></div></td>
                         </tr>
```

Comment: Please publish the code related to question

Answer (score 1):

I did it quickly so there are some issues like the max bar which is greater than 100%. However, you can easily use it with your own code.
I used a listener which is notified each time you're increasing the progressbar value !

```js
class Listener {
  constructor(value){
    this.value = value;
    this.bar = $('.progress-bar');
  }
  
  notify(value){
    $('#message').text(value);
   
    if (value < 25){
      this.bar.css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    else if (value < 50){
      this.bar.css('background-color', 'blue');
    }
    else{
      this.bar.css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }
  }
};

let listener = new Listener(0);

let timer = setInterval(function(){
    let width = $('.progress-bar').width();
    if (width >= 100) clearInterval(this);
    let newValue = (($('.progress-bar').width() + 100) / $('.progress').width()) * 100;
    $('.progress-bar').width($('.progress-bar').width() + 100);
    listener.notify(newValue);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div id="progress" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>

<div id="message"></div>
```

Hope this helped !